# How to pass data from on component to another using Angular EventEmitter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

There are two Angular components: the button defined as the `app-widget-a` and `app-widget-b` widget that is supposed to show the message when the `app-widget-a` button is clicked.

When `app-widget-a` button is clicked its emitter emits the text message. It is fetched by the `fetchEvent` function defined in the `app.component.ts` script. This function logs that it successfully fetched the event (a message). But it fails to call the `showMessage` function defined in the `widget_b.component.ts` raising the exception that `Property 'showMessage' does not exist on type 'Component'.`

Here is the link to Stackblitz project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r9hwbs

How to fix the error?

[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r9hwbs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to use service + subject when working with data being transfered between siblings. This will make your code much cleaner, in my experience it's much better.

```
// data.service.ts
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  private dataTransferSubject = new Subject<string>()
  dataTransferObservable = this.dataTransferSubject.asObservable();

  push(str: string) {
    this.dataTransferSubject.next(str);
  }
}

// widget-a.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-widget-a',
  template: '<button (click)="onButtonClick()"> widget-a! </button>'
})
export class WidgetAComponent implements OnInit {    
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  onButtonClick() {
    this.dataService.push("This is Component A's shared value");
  }
}

// widget-b.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-widget-b',
  template: '<p>widget-b value: {{value}}</p>'
})
export class WidgetBComponent implements OnInit {
  value = "This is Component B's value";
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.dataTransferObservable.subscribe(str => {
      this.value=str;
    });
  }
}
```

Similar example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-msdqzd)

If you use it this way, don't forget to unsubscribe on ngOnDestroy.

Comment: The approach mentioned in Stackblitz is perfectly correct but it would be more useful if you could mention the core coding portion in the answer because it will decrease dependency on other applications. I have seen many codepen links mentioned in the StackOverflow answers become non-working/non-existing over time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how you would set that up.

1. Create a service that you can inject into components so you can listen to the `EventEmitter`
2. Consume the service in your components

**Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class EventService {
  public emitter: EventEmitter<string | null>;
  constructor() {
    this.emitter = new EventEmitter<string>(null);
  }
  broadcastMessage(message: string): void {
    this.emitter.emit(message);
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  private readonly _eventService: EventService;
  public message: string;
  constructor(eventService: EventService) {
    this._eventService = eventService;
    this._eventService.emitter.subscribe( message => this.message = message);
  }
  sendMessage(): void {
    const message = `The time is ${new Date().getTime()}`;
    this._eventService.broadcastMessage(message);
  }
}
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6m6ctm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) demonstrating the pattern.

If you are trying to inject/use an `EventEmitter` that exists in another component without using a service, it gets a little more complicated. You would first have to establish a reference to the Component. Once you have that you can do `Component.instance.<public property>` (or use whatever binding method you are working with).

IMO it's too much code/work to manage component references. The standard way of doing this sort of thing typically involves creating a service to centralize your event emissions.

On a side note, if you're trying to manage some kind of state via `EventEmitter`, I would recommend shifting towards [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/) to make your application more reactive and manage state more efficiently.

Comment: The approach mentioned in Stackblitz is perfectly correct but it could be little confusing for the beginners to understand it. If the emit and subscribe were in two separate components, it would have perfectly matched the requirement of this question.

Comment: Brevity is preferred as it makes answers more readable. Secondly, the user's questions make it clear they know how to consume it in the components, they are just missing the service piece.